# Mobile App HTML5 Game Development (Tools)

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

I'd like to use Html5 canvas and js to write a game for mobile devices and web. I've seen development tools out there such as [Construct 2](http://www.scirra.com/) [(tutorial)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgIt3vAajx8) and sites that explain how to create html5 games from scratch like [Lost Decade Games](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/). Is there and advantage and/or recommendation for either method especially for someone just getting started that has several years of WinApp development experience?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IMHO, if you feel comfortable with development, you'll learn much more by building a game from scratch than by using tools.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too. Just don't want to waste a lot of time (other than learning) if there are tools to accomplish the same thing.